# Better way to set unix permissions when deploying war file

Tags: java, oracle, unix, oracle9i

We have a vendor application where we download their updates and deploy a war file.  We are deploying the war file on a unix application server running oracle application server 9i.  I believe when we deploy the war file, we remove the previous install and then deploy the new war file.  When we deploy the war file, sometimes we have to manually set the unix file permissions for the class and other files.  We do this so all the unix user ids can run the processes they need.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comment to Steven's answer, how about setting `umask` to `000` for the user that deploys the war file? (This would be oracleas, the umask variable is often set in the .profile of that user.) The umask (which is now probably set to 027) masks out file permissions, 000 does not mask out anything, resulting in permissions for others.

Comment: umask 000 is a bad idea.  You should at least mask out group / other write.

Comment: @Steven, yes as a general rule you are right. Given his problem though (he is looking for another way to chmod the files back to having other's permissions) it is the first step to either a solution or to narrow down the possibilities. Either way I do not think a downvote is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about OAS... but I'd presume the files unpacked from the war file would be owned and accessed by the user as which OAS is running.  Is that not correct? Can you explain a bit more about what is actually happening or why this is a problem?

Following your additional comments below...

It sounds like your security model is simply not quite right: you associate OAS and its data with the dba group, but some dependencies of OAS (and its data) are not in that group.  I have a few suggestions:

1. Create a new group for OAS and its dependencies, and assess which users in the dba group also need to be in that group.  If required, keep the OAS user in the dba group too.

   Deploy the war file using a script which waits for deployment to be complete and changes the permissions for you.

   Fix your dependencies. It sort of sounds like some of the classes in the war file should rather be deployed elsewhere - outside the application context - and referenced there.  They can then have the new more appropriate group, to which you would add your batch process user and the OAS user.

Comment: The war file is deployed and the files are owned by a user id oracleas and the group is dba.  The deployed file permissions are 750 (rwxr-x---).  We have a unix id r6schd that is not part of the dba group that runs a batch process that is part of the deployed application.  We are having to set the directory permissions for the deployed app to 755(rwxr-xr-x) and the app files below them as appropriate.  I know we could add the r6schd user id to the dba group, but the app dba does not want to do this.  So I am looking for a better way to get the permissions set correct on deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few HINTs: 
There is no way to set file permissions within a war/jar.

The permissions depend on the oracleas user's umask.  Change that and
you'll be all set.

Is there a way you can keep the war packaged?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Why would you want to keep the war file packaged?